# NDVI Modis Times Series Animation - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis

I don't understand JavaScript. Following the instructions, I made a beautiful [animation](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a33ba66ee8ee4b62628304c60de9c1ba) with following code:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[21.171108568177974, 52.71072901884085],
          [21.171108568177974, 43.97825621993774],
          [40.66085466192797, 43.97825621993774],
          [40.66085466192797, 52.71072901884085]]], null, false);

// Fetch a MODIS NDVI collection and select NDVI.
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A2').select('NDVI');

// Define a mask to clip the NDVI data by.
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Ukraine'));

// Define the regional bounds of animation frames.
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[21.171108568177974,43.97825621993774],
    [40.66085466192797,43.97825621993774],
    [40.66085466192797,52.71072901884085],
     [21.171108568177974,52.71072901884085],
    [21.171108568177974,43.97825621993774]]],
  null, false
);

// Add day-of-year (DOY) property to each image.
col = col.map(function(img) {
  var doy = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
  return img.set('doy', doy);
});

// Get a collection of distinct images by 'doy'.
var distinctDOY = col.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2021-04-01');

// Define a filter that identifies which images from the complete
// collection match the DOY from the distinct DOY collection.
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'doy', rightField: 'doy'});

// Define a join.
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches');

// Apply the join and convert the resulting FeatureCollection to an
// ImageCollection.
var joinCol = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(distinctDOY, col, filter));

// Apply median reduction among matching DOY collections.
var comp = joinCol.map(function(img) {
  var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    img.get('doy_matches')
  );
  return doyCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
});

// Define RGB visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 9000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = comp.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).clip(mask);
});

Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: rgbVis,
  description: 'sfVideoExample',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 12,
  region: region
});
```

But I need animation once a year 2013-2021, not every 16 days. If possible, then the average for the year. If not, then March, or April.

Please tell me what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your above code produces 190 images every 16 days so, it works well with 12 frames per second. However, for an animation once a year between 2013-2021, a lower value for this parameter is required because there are only 9 years in obtained image collection (years). In following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c9b9bacbdbecfc16c89ca89bad423666), I used only 1 frame per second and it works well. As said before, yearly collection used for animation is named years.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[21.171108568177974, 52.71072901884085],
          [21.171108568177974, 43.97825621993774],
          [40.66085466192797, 43.97825621993774],
          [40.66085466192797, 52.71072901884085]]], null, false);

// Fetch a MODIS NDVI collection and select NDVI.
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A2').select('NDVI');

print(col);

var start = 2013;

//make a list of years and filter the modisNDVI  
var years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021, 1).map(function(year){
  var start = ee.Number(year);
  var end = start.add(ee.Number(1));
  var ndviMeanYear = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start, end, 'year')).mean();
  return ndviMeanYear.set('year', start);
});

years = ee.ImageCollection(years);

print(years);

// Define a mask to clip the NDVI data by.
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Ukraine'));

// Define the regional bounds of animation frames.
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[21.171108568177974,43.97825621993774],
    [40.66085466192797,43.97825621993774],
    [40.66085466192797,52.71072901884085],
     [21.171108568177974,52.71072901884085],
    [21.171108568177974,43.97825621993774]]],
  null, false
);

// Define RGB visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 9000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = years.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).clip(mask);
});

Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: rgbVis,
  description: 'sfVideoExample',
  dimensions: 720,
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  region: region
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help.

Perhaps it will be useful to someone. In order not to waste 4 months, slightly changed the provided code

var start = 2012-4-1;

//make a list of years and filter the modisNDVI  
var years = ee.List.sequence(2012-4-1, 2021-4-1, 1).map(function(year){
  var start = ee.Number(year);
  var end = start.add(ee.Number(1));
  var ndviMeanYear = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start, end, 'year')).mean();
  return ndviMeanYear.set('year', start);
});